# How can I make this neo4j query faster?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a database that contains these four nodes:

> Store, Guitar, GuitarModel, Accessory

*Guitar refers to a specific guitar that a person can own/play

```
optional match (a:Store), (b:Guitar), (c:GuitarModel), (d:Accessory)
where a.StoreNumber ="1234" and (a)-[:ContainsGuitar]->(b) and
(b)-[:IS_OF_MODEL]->(c) and 
((d)-[:COMES_STANDARD]-(c) OR (d)-[:COMES_OPTIONAL]-(c) OR (d)-:COMES_OPTION_UPGRADE]-(c) OR (d)-[:COMES_UPGRADE]-(c))
return b.name, collect(d.name)
```

My issue right now is this query is pretty slow it takes about 120,000ms to perform.

I have 67,000 nodes and 131,000 relationships.

So am I doing something wrong that making this slow?

Comment: When you have pattern predicates in your WHERE clause, it's used as a filter after your match. So you're getting the specific store cross product with all :Guitars, cross product with all :GuitarModels, cross product with all :Accessories, and THEN filtering to those that have relationships to the specific store. As logisima says, use the pattern in your MATCH instead, that way it just traverses from the :Store directly to the associated nodes and avoids multiple cross products.

Answer (score 1):

- Do you have an index/constraint on `:Store(StoreNumber)` ?
- Why are you only using an optional match ? You can combine `MATCH` & `OPTIONAL MATCH`
- Why are you doing your pattern in the `WHERE` clause ? You should put it directly in a `MATCH`.

I think that your query creates a cartesian product between nodes, that's why it's so slow.

Can you try this query :

```
MATCH 
  (:Store { StoreNumber:"1234" })-[:ContainsGuitar]->(b)
RETURN 
  b.name, 
  [(b)-[:IS_OF_MODEL]->(:GuitarModel)-[:COMES_STANDARD|COMES_OPTIONAL|COMES_OPTION_UPGRADE|COMES_UPGRADE]-(d:Accessory) | d.name]
```